# Inductor circuit simulation trouble

Tags: inductor

First time here, I'm having trouble at checking my solution in a task I got.

The task says that V<sub>source</sub> is 2 V when t < 0 and when T= ≥ 0 V<sub>source</sub> = 0.
The circuit it self built from one voltage source one resistor and one inductor. (R = 2 Ω, L = 10 μH.)

The thing is I try to simulate it as mentioned with the V<sub>source</sub> that it will start with 2 V and after t = 0+ it will drop to 0 V will appreciate any kind of help!

[image: This is the image of the circuit]

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. So, you forgot to ask a question and to detail the problem that arises when you do this.

Comment: When I start a simulation it shows me a steady 2V no reaction overtime as detailed in the task

Comment: Show the V1 settings

Comment: http://prntscr.com/rifdfs

Comment: @Uncle: Please post all the information in your question, not scattered through the comments and external sites. That way we'll all see it.

Answer (score 0):

Show the V1 settings – Andy aka

[image]

That's your problem - it's just set up as a continuous DC voltage - you need to use the setting I've highlighted in red.